# TypeError: iterating over dictionary in python not working

Tags: python, dictionary

iterating over multiple objects works fine, but it throws an error for one object. How does this work?

```
dic1={1:10,2:20}
dic2={3:30,4:40}
dic3={5:50,6:60}
dic_new = {}
for x in (dic1,dic2,dic3):
    dic_new.update(x)
print(dic_new)
{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60}



dic1={1:10,2:20}
dic2={3:30,4:40}
dic3={5:50,6:60}
dic_new = {}
for x in dic1:
    dic_new.update(x)
print(dic_new)

dic_new.update(x)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `for x in dic1`, have a look at what this is iterating over

Comment: it doesn't update value to new_dic

Comment: Thats because you are iterating over the keys of that dictionary. Where as in the first loop you are iterating over other dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

[`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two).

In the first for loop, `x` is `dic1`, `dic2` and so on, which means that `update` is called with a dictionary. This is supported and works fine.

In the second for loop, `x` is the keys of the `dic1` dictionary i.e. `1` and `2`, which are of type `int`. `int` is neither a dictionary nor an iterable of key/value pairs, so an exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating what you think.

In your first exemple, you assign to x each dict, and then update dict_new with them.

In the second exemple, you are only iterating over dic1 kwys.

```py
for x in dic1:
    print(x)

#1
#2
```

Now if you want to it with a single item, here are options you may used.

```py
#Option 1

new_dict.update(dic1)

# Option 2

for key, value in dic1.items():
    new_dict.update((key, value))
```